# How to get a bot to send a message as the program is shutting down

Tags: discord.py

I'm using Heroku to keep my discord bot running, and everything works fine, there's just one thing I want to add, but I've no idea how I can do it. I'd like for whenever the program shuts down, or stops running, for the bot to send a message. Can anyone give me an example of how this is possible? Thx in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py has a `on_disconnect` event which, unfortunately, won't let you send a message (as the bot already disconnected), but you can print something (e.g. the time the bot disconnected) when the bot disconnects. Unfortunately, it's impossible to send a message once the bot has disconnected.